# using "vim" can lead ssh timeout but "top" not

Tags: ssh

When I use ssh to log in a remote server and open vim, if I don't type any words the session will timeout and I have to log in again.
But if I run command like top the session will never timeout?
What's the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the behavior you're seeing isn't related to `vim` or to `top`. Chances are good some router along the way is culling "dead" TCP sessions. This is often done by a [NAT firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) or a [stateful firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall) to reduce memory pressure and protect against simple denial of service attacks.

Probably the `ServerAliveInterval` configuration option can keep your idle-looking sessions from being reaped:

```
 ServerAliveInterval
         Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no
         data has been received from the server, ssh(1) will
         send a message through the encrypted channel to request
         a response from the server.  The default is 0,
         indicating that these messages will not be sent to the
         server, or 300 if the BatchMode option is set.  This
         option applies to protocol version 2 only.
         ProtocolKeepAlives and SetupTimeOut are Debian-specific
         compatibility aliases for this option.
```

Try adding `ServerAliveInterval 180` to your `~/.ssh/config` file. This will ask for the keepalive probes every three minutes, which should be faster than many firewall timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

vim will just sit there waiting for input, and (unless you've got a clock or something on the terminal screen) will also produce no output. If this continues for very long, most firewalls will see the connection as dead and kill them, since there's no activity.

Top, by comparison, updates the screen once every few seconds, which is seen as activity and the connection is kept open, since there IS data flowing over it on a regular basis.

There are options you can add the SSH server's configuration to send timed "null" packets to keep a connection alive, even though no actual user data is going across the link: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/keep-your-linux-ssh-session-from-disconnecting/

Comment: Well Thank you very much. Is that Top send "message" to me on server's initiative or My computer ask top to send message to me?

Comment: It's top's initiative. It's a 'live' display of system activity, and the output is refreshed periodically. You can set the interval with the `i` key, if I remember right.

Answer (score 0):

Because "top" is always returning data through your SSH console, it will remain active.

"vim" will not because it is static and only transmits data according to your key presses.

The lack of transferred data causes the SSH session to time out